# testing scroll down button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am testing a scroll down button on a website and wondering why the action does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="style_sheet.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>COS</title>
  <script>
    $(function() {
       $('.scroll-down').click (function() {
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section.ok').offset().top }, 'slow');
         return false;
       });
     });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <section>
        <p>SCROLL DOWN CSS</p>
        <a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true"></a>
    </section>
    <section class="ok">
      <p>OK SCROLL !</p>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

If I understand right, the javascript should be located in head. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are using JQuery syntax without referencing jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In the code you've posted, there's no jQuery linked in.

Try inserting `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
`

Comment: If you want to post a answer to such a simple mistake I would recommend you include a link to the [**jQuery API**](https://api.jquery.com/). This will make your answer more detailed and helpful as the OP can then use that link to learn more about the use of `jQuery`. Also pointing out that the `jQuery` library must be added before attempting to use any `jQuery`. *"Order does matter"*